# Where should a gem store log files?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am building a ruby gem that should output a logfile. Where is it a good practice to store log files?

I am extracting this functionality from a Rails website I am building, and there I could simply log in the `log/` directory.

Comment: Is this intended for a public gem? If so, I would advise supporting a way of users providing a logger object, rather than have the gem determine logging routes.

Comment: I like this answer, I'd like to select it as I'm going to use it. A big plus would be a short description of how to do this: should it be an initializer argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, make the path configurable (`.rc` file, switch, rails/rack config, whatever).

If it's a Rack middleware, add the possibility to specify it in the constructor's arguments.

If no log path is provided, fallback to detecting a log directory. (I vaguely remember it being `config.paths['log']` in Rails, but be sure that `config` actually points to something before using that in your gem if it can be used outside of Rails.)

And if all else fails, log to nowhere...

Also, allow to disable logging if you enable it by default. Not everyone wants logs.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I will probably log to nowhere by default.

Comment: One grudge with this answer: I tried `if defined? Rails and defined? config` and config is not defined even when running from rails. What gives?

Comment: I'm afraid my Rails-fu is a too rusty to help out on that. :-(

Comment: In case someone is wondering, I think the problem was that I was doing this in an initializer, and the Rails config object is available after initialization, if I recall correctly. Didn't find a solution.